# Android BitmapFactory.decodeStream() return null

Tags: android, inputstream, bitmapfactory

I am trying to convert an InputSteam (of a video) to a Bitmap however decodeStream() returns null.

Code sample:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.test1);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap surface = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
//surface is null
```

Is it because the input steam is too big? If so, how would I go about trimming the input stream to only read 1 1920x1080 frame?
This need to be pretty fast, I tried using MediaMetadataRetriever but it was too slow. The big picture is that I am trying to draw a .mp4 to a Canvas.

Comment: Are you trying to play a .mp4 to a Canvas?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Even if it works, the performance would likely be horrendous, what are you trying to achieve with this setup, maybe there are better ways.

Comment: I am trying to draw a video to a live wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Bitmap surface = decodeFile(new File("file path here"));

    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

      int IMGAE_REZ  = 100;

        try {

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){

                if(width_tmp/2<IMGAE_REZ || height_tmp/2<IMGAE_REZ)
                break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The function returned null and the outWidth was set to -1 indicating an error in decoding.